# C# - Replace a static string in a class with a value from a form

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a program that is running on multiple monitors.
I need to have a sound function that is shared between them.
I need a winform to be open on both monitors at the same time.
When the user does various things the program will respond with some sound alerts that need to be set at runtime.

I have everything working except not able to pass the location of the sound files onto my class that is handling the sound generation routine.

Here is the main code for the startup form, this is where I am getting the location of the file and storing it in workstation_settings.bad_alert_1_path.

```
       public startupForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        first_choice_mainEntities db = new first_choice_mainEntities();

        //setup defaults in case we cannot find our configurations
        systems_configuration default_workstation_settings = new systems_configuration();
        default_workstation_settings.control_monitor_number = 0;
        default_workstation_settings.display_monitor_number = 1;
        default_workstation_settings.good_alert_1_path = "c:\\Workstation_Settings\\sounds\\boxing_bell.wav";
        default_workstation_settings.bad_alert_1_path = "c:\\Workstation_Settings\\sounds\\Air_horn.wav";
        default_workstation_settings.branch_id = "ERR";
        default_workstation_settings.short_machine_name = "Unknown";
        default_workstation_settings.local_machine_desc = "Unknown - missing config file";

        //go get the computer name from the text file
        string workstationID = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C:\\Workstation_settings\\workstationID.txt");

        //now go see if this ID is in the database
        var workstation_settings = (from w in db.systems_configuration where w.machine_id == workstationID select w).FirstOrDefault();

        if (workstation_settings is null)
        {
            //use default settings
            workstation_settings = default_workstation_settings;
        }

        //get a array of all the screens connected
        Screen[] sc;
        sc = Screen.AllScreens;

        //setup the display monitor (the top monitor mounted on the pole)
        display_monitor_default_form ds = new display_monitor_default_form();
        ds.Left = sc[Convert.ToInt16(workstation_settings.display_monitor_number)].Bounds.Left;
        ds.Top = sc[Convert.ToInt16(workstation_settings.display_monitor_number)].Bounds.Top;
        ds.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
        ds.Show();

        //setup the control monitor (the touchscreen on the cart)
        main_control_form f = new main_control_form();
        f.workstation_settings = workstation_settings;
        f.Left = sc[Convert.ToInt16(workstation_settings.control_monitor_number)].Bounds.Left;
        f.Top = sc[Convert.ToInt16(workstation_settings.control_monitor_number)].Bounds.Top;
        f.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
        f.Show();

    }
```

And here is the class called soundsForMe wiht a hard coded string called badAlert_1_location that needs replaced with the value in workstation_settings.bad_alert_1_path from the startupForm:

```
  public class soundsForMe
  {
    //REPLACE THIS WITH THE LOCATION SET IN THE startupForm()!!!
    static string  badAlert_1_location = "c:\\Workstation_Settings\\sounds\\boxing_bell.wav";

    System.Media.SoundPlayer badAlert_1 = new System.Media.SoundPlayer(badAlert_1_location);
    System.Media.SoundPlayer goodAlert_1 = new System.Media.SoundPlayer("c:\\sounds\\boxing_bell.wav");

    public System.Media.SoundPlayer BadAlert_1 { get => badAlert_1; }
    public System.Media.SoundPlayer GoodAlert_1 { get => goodAlert_1; }

 }
```

And finally, here is where I am calling a test of the sound from one of my forms to make sure it works.
It works as is, but the sound path needs to not be hard coded:

```
    public partial class main_control_form : Telerik.WinControls.UI.RadForm
{
    public systems_configuration workstation_settings { get; set; }

    public soundsForMe play = new soundsForMe();

    public main_control_form()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        play.BadAlert_1.Play();

    }
}
```

Thank you ---

Comment: One possible way would be to raise an event, and all screens ( I suppose apps or processes ) can subscribe and act on it

Comment: Well, I have the sound routine working fine I just need to get the ability to not use a hard coded location.  The reason I am doing it this way also is to have the sound stay loaded in memory (hopefully) as there was some lag before.

Comment: you can try something with SignalR for instance? try to signal all at the same time.. but I think the OS availability etc.. will have influence if the sound plays or not at the same time.
But I'm guessing that will envolve some kind of publisher/subscriber pattern.

Comment: If the file location changes then you must create a new instance of SoundPlayer.

Comment: The file location won't change from run to run, I just don't want to hard code it.